# Using custom functions on pandas group by aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  dataframe like this,

```
>>> data = {
    'year':[2019, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2019],
    'provider':['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'T'],
    'price':[100, 122, 0, 150, 120, 80],
    'count':[20, 15, 24, 16, 24, 10]
}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   year provider  price  count
0  2019        X    100     20
1  2020        X    122     15
2  2020        Y      0     24
3  2019        Z    150     16
4  2020        Z    120     24
5  2019        T     80     10
```

And this is expected output:

```
  provider  price_rate  count_rate
0        X        0.22       -0.25
1        Z       -0.20        0.50
```

I want to group prices on providers and find price, count differences between 2019 and 2020. 
If there is no price or count record at 2020 or 2019, don't want to see related provider.

Comment: Are there always only 1 or 2 rows per provider?

Comment: Yeap always 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the assumption that there are always only 1 or 2 rows per provider, we can first `sort_values` on `year` to make sure `2019` comes before `2020`.

Then we `groupby` on provider and `divide` the rows of `price` and `count` and substract 1.

```
df = df.sort_values('year')
grp = (
    df.groupby('provider')
      .apply(lambda x: x[['price', 'count']].div(x[['price', 'count']].shift()).sub(1))
)

dfnew = df[['provider']].join(grp).dropna()
```

---

```
  provider  price  count
1        X   0.22  -0.25
4        Z  -0.20   0.50
```

---

Or only vectorized methods:

```
dfnew = df[df['provider'].duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values(['provider', 'year'])
dfnew[['price', 'count']] = (
    dfnew[['price', 'count']].div(dfnew[['price', 'count']].shift()).sub(1)
)

dfnew = dfnew[dfnew['provider'].eq(dfnew['provider'].shift())].drop('year', axis=1)
```

---

```
  provider  price  count
1        X   0.22  -0.25
4        Z  -0.20   0.50
```

Comment: Just for your convenience, I added another method, which might (not 100% sure) run faster on larger datasets. @AlperenTaşkın

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
final = (df.set_index(['provider','year']).groupby(level=0)
      .pct_change().dropna().droplevel(1).add_suffix('_count').reset_index())
```

---

```
  provider  price_rate  count_rate
0        X        0.22       -0.25
1        Z       -0.20        0.50
```